# What things are handy to have in a horse owner's kit?

Tags: health, grooming, horses

Horses are complex animals to keep as pets. They require a lot of care in ways that may not always be apparent. After many years of accumulating knowledge from research and experience, it would have been handy to have a list of what to keep in your kit when owning a horse.

Comment: Plan to write an answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A horse owner should have some different kits that cover up.
I will mention not only those things which a horse owner renting at a barn with many other people will own, but also those, which the stable owner will find useful. During my work at stables we needed most of them and I wouldn't want to miss any of it somewhere in the stable. The list might be incomplete.

- horse pass
- Knife
- Scissor
- Halters
- Ropes
- Hoofpick
- Brushes, soft, hard, ...
- scrunchies
- some stuff of whatever kind to protect against flies and other insects
- buckets (at least two or three, one for water, one for medical stuff, one for cleaning, ..)
- sponges. i'd recomment at least 2 for the horse (genitals <> head), 1 for medical stuff (replace after use), 1 for cleaning
- hay net
- nippers (in the case of horse shoes), all kinds of tools in general that might be needed to free a horse from whatever your stable is built of
- Diapers (they make excellent hoof-bandages)
- First-Aid-stuff for both human and horse
- zinc ointment (at least i'd recommend some)
- milking grease
- Emergency phone numbers and addresses (!)
- Disinfectant stuff like Iod, but also other variations that allow sewing lateron (medicine-lexicon at hand is always a nice thing)
- Rugs. At least one, better two so you can change them
- Towels (the normal cloth ones, but also steril ones)
- thermometer with rope (!)
- gloves. all sorts of. warm ones, handy ones for work, medical ones, shoulderlong ones for breeders, ...
- maybe drugs like Vetranquil (if you are experienced enough to know how to deal with that and cannot rely on having a vet there fast enough on emergencies)
- transport-related stuff in case of emergency
- material and tools needed for repairing stuff, especially for fences.
- spare colostrum and foal milk in case you are breeding. mare could die or not able to give milk for another reason. in this case, a lot of towels, and iod.
- sad to mention, but in case you live far away from medical treatment, some gun might come in useful sometimes, you do not want to wait for a horse to bleed out when it tore off a hoof and vet cannot come in time for whatever reason :-/

..

Depending on the stable many things can be shared, but it is important to have access to all this in case of emergency.

Comment: I would add an old bra, it could make a good bandage in case of eye injury...